# Android localized JSON files

Tags: android, json, localization

I have two JSON files (both named countries): one in english inside the `raw` folder, and one in french inside the `raw-fr` folder. But no matter what language I select on the device, the app always loads the file under `raw`. I'm loading the JSON file as follows:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.countries);
```

The folder structure is:

> - res
>
>   - drawable
>   - layout
>   - values
>   - values-fr
>   - ...
>   - raw
>   - raw-fr

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel: He has already translated the text himself in french in the file that is put in `raw-fr` folder.

Comment: Yes, the file under `raw` is in english, and the file under `raw-fr` is in french. The app always loads the one in english.

Comment: Just for confirmation, can you post your directory structure here

Comment: Seems like it's picking the default for you. Can you rename your `raw` folder to `raw-en` and check what's happening?

Comment: @Yashasvi: updated the question with the folder structure. I've changed the `raw` folder to `raw-en`, and it still uses the english file all the time.

Comment: I'll keep the translations in some string resources XML files, and use the id's on the JSON. Maybe that's the only option…

Comment: I Just checked it with `values` and `values-fr`. It picks up the string from `values-fr` when I choose french language in my device.

Comment: It also loads the correct `values-fr` file on my case. It just won't load the JSON file on `raw-fr`…

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are not choosing the right language. It only chooses the default language if it can't find a resource directory corresponding to the selected language. 
If the default is not present, the application crashes (as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)).

Try removing `values` folder and then see what happens.

OR

Try renaming `values` to `values-en` so that it's used only for english language.

P.S. I just tried with `values` and `values-fr`. It picks up the string from `values-fr` when I choose french language on my device.

Comment: I thinks I'm choosing the right language because it also loads the correct `values-fr` file. It just won't load the JSON file on `raw-fr`…

Comment: oh ok, I'll check with `raw-fr' and get back to you